# Does the Inspiron 15 3537 have a PCIE or MXM slot?

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, pci-express, dell-inspiron

So I was wondering if the Dell Inspiron 15 3537 has either a PCIE or M PCIE or MXM slot on it? I currently own one but can't get the keyboard off to open it up and have a look. It does have a dedicated AMD 8850m GPU so I was wondering if that was soldered onto the board or not and if I could remove it and put it into another laptop? I'm going to post another question asking if the Dell Vostro 3550 has a PCIE or M PCIE or MXM slot for a GPU as well sepearately in another post. The idea is t swap the GPU in my Inspiron into the Vostro.

Anyway any help is appreciated,

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Swapping the GPUs is 1- very risky because the are soldered to the mainboard and 2- almost certainly will not work because unlike CPUs, they don't have standardized sockets, even if they do, the circuits around them will not be the same (a lot of resistors and capacitors won't have the right value)

On the other hand, laptops have a PCI-E port, it's populated by your internal wireless adapter.
You can connect an external wireless adapter via USB and use that port to connect an external GPU using eGPU, Some laptops even have a PCMCIA express port that you can connect to

look here :http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1191969-external-gpu-for-laptops-supercharge-your-graphics/

and here :http://forum.techinferno.com/diy-e-gpu-projects/2109-diy-egpu-experiences-%5Bversion-2-0%5D.html#post27126

Comment: Thanks, I think you confirmed it for me that I can't do what I was planning on doing. Might as well save up to spend it on a new gpu for my desktop. Sure I could use an eGPU but from what I've seen it just ends up too much of a hassle.